# Object not defined but i think scope and declaration is ok

Tags: javascript, object, defined

When I try to run a method from this object it says that the object is not defined. I'm sorry if it's a stupid question I checked many times and cant seem to find an error so I appreciate your help and patience.

```
let Sunce= {
  dvaujedan: function (name){
    this.prva(name);
    this.druga();
  },
  prva: (name){
    switch(name){
      case "Elena":
        player = new Player ("Elena" , 100, 200, 50, 100, 400);
        break;
      case "Anabel":
        player = new Player ("Anabel" , 200, 300, 150, 200, 100);
        break;
      case "Silvia":
        player = new Player ("Silvia" , 100, 200, 50, 200, 300);
        break;
    } 

    let getinterface =document.querySelector(".interface");
    getinterface.innerHTML= '<img src="img/player/' + 
      player.name.toLowerCase() + '.jpg"> <h3>' + 
      player.name + '</h3><p>Speed:' + player.speed + '</p><p>Health:' + 
      player.health + '</p><p>Damage:' + player.damage + 
     '</p><p>Agility:' + player.agility + 
     '</p><p>Mana:' + player.mana + '</p>';
    },
    druga: (){}
}
```

Comment: Which object is undefined? Which line says that? Please provide a [mcve]. Also *please* format your code. Right now it's unreadable. Not to mention it's syntactically incorrect - I don't know if your real code is wrong or it's a copy/paste error introduced the error.

Comment: your question is somewhat vague and your code is all over the place. Please spend more time cleaning your question so we can answer it.

Comment: Where is the code for your Player object?

Comment: You seem to be missing the keyword `function` on two of your functions.

Comment: thank you all, im aware im bad at code formating, ill try to work on that. missing function keywords was the problem i quess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the object will cause `SyntaxError` because of `prva` and `druga`. You should add `function` for those 2 functions.

```js
dvaujedan: function (name){
...
},
prva: function (name){
...
},
druga: function (){}
```